# Choosing a Web User Interface library

Tags: java, vaadin, dhtmlx, webui

I was asked by the company I work to create a web user interface for a fleet managment system they have developed.

This system is written in java so I thought  that the library I should compatible with java or language neutral. Additionally it should be free/open source, as well as full-featured

After a small search I found the following libraries:

1)
http://dhtmlx.com/index.shtml

2) https://vaadin.com/home

Currently I face the following critical question: should I rely on a server side library for the creation of the User Interface or should I prefer a client side one ?

What is more are there any other important web user interface libraries that I should be aware of ?

Since I do not have any experience in the topic, every advice will be very useful : )

Comment: Although I am not fluent in javascript etc... Is there any reason I should prefer dhtmlx over vaadin ??

Comment: What is more does this library worth the effort? http://echo.nextapp.com/site/

Comment: The future of Web programming is a statefull programming model transparent to the programmer. Wicket could be an alternative - http://wicket.apache.org/.

Comment: I came across another library : http://jquerytools.org/ Do you think it worths the effort of trying it out? it seems to be simple

Comment: Tried it. "Although I am not fluent in javascript etc"... You'll get lost very quickly. If you really insist on using Javascript as a UI, then go for the cutting edge - http://jqueryui.com/ and http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ for the MVC on the client side. As I said, it's complicated to develop the web application alone, if you have to learn Javascript and browser compatibility at the same time... JQuery is (fully)portable, that should save you some time. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say go for Vaadin. It's Swing like development without the HTML, JavaScript, CSS and any other "helpfull libraries". Even though this is a polyglot development time, pick simplicity and productivity over flexibility. You'll thank yourself in the long run.

Comment: Yes, it performs validation on the server side. It causes some performance issues, but I wouldn't be worried about that. Java is one of the fastest languages out there. You should concern yourself about productivity, not about performance. There is a link(can't find it right now) on the Vaadin home page or blog about their performance. Needless to say, it's fast.

Comment: Vaadin code executes in the server-side? If yes would it cause performance issues ? (Btw what do you mean by polyglot development time?) (question answered above)

Comment: Here is the link about the performance - https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-scalability-study-quicktickets. Vaadin is based on the GWT framework. It's sort of a server-client communication without the need to code in 15 languages(Java compiles to Javascript). That's what I meant by polyglot - programming polyglotism(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglotism). And Vaadin uses that sort of communication(it's built on top of GWT), but uses the validation on the server.

Comment: what are the cons in using vaardin ? can i use it to include google maps or similar widgets in my apps ?

Comment: The cons are, well, the cons of any component based UI. And, as you mentioned, performance. To use google maps as a part of Vaadin, no, you should create your own component. You can create it using GWT(https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html). That's the drawback - you have a limited number of components. The components are rich, simple to use, but if you want something custom - you have to create it. There are user components as well - you can check it out. To sum up - the cons are performance and flexibility.

Comment: The Vaadin directory has some stuff, http://vaadin.com/addon/googlemapwidget as an example. And you can always create own special widgets if needed. Then using regular GWT stuff on client side and wrapping to a Vaadin component.

Answer (score 2):

I personally recomend you to use a server-side framework (server side library). Performance is an important thing so why should your business logic be on the client side? You have to do a validation always on server-side so why to do it twice? You are more independent from different end-devices like tablets, smartphones and whatever. To sum up: let the client side for UI and do the rest on server-side.

I have no performance problems with vaadin.